# How to install an older version of M2 with composer?

Tags: magento-2.1

I need to install one minor version down from the current 2.1.2 using Composer.

I try:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition 2.1.0 /home/m2track/public_html
```

However I get :
" Could not parse version constraint /home/m2track/public_html: Invalid version string "/home/m2track/public_html" as an error.

What is the correct syntax to install 2.1.0 or 2.1.1 using composer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had the version in the wrong place:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition /home/m2track/public_html 2.1.0
```

Answer (score 6):

Try with:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.1.0 /your/destionation/path
```

Comment: don't know why the other answer is set as correct. With yours I was able to install an older version. With the other I was getting "could not parse version constraint"

Comment: take out the **'s , was meant to bold the version #. I just tried it again, and it works.  I'll edit my answer though to remove that.